# Encrypt Firestore bundles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As Firebase supports bundle feature for the Firestore data. To make this bundle work for all users, it has to be a public file or public endpoint so that cache will work.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching#built-in_caching_for

How to encrypt these bundle files? So that if someone knows the bundle file URL then they must have to decrypt the data to load/read the bundle.

I already contacted Firebase support. But this is the reply from them:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase to end-to-end encrypt the data in Firestore bundles. But since they're just a file, you can apply any encryption scheme you want on them, as long as you can decrypt it on the device where you will then feed the data into Firestore through its API.

Since we can't recommend any specific encryption mechanism here, I recommend doing a search for an [API for encrypting/decrypting files](https://www.google.com/search?q=API+for+encrypting%2Fdecrypting+files).